# ember-cli 0.0.37 import new syntax and ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've recently upgraded from ember-cli 0.0.36 to 0.0.37 and have been struggling to import ember-data. Although seemingly simple, it's not working for me. In the Brocfile.js, the old import was

```
app.import({
    development: 'vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js',
    production: 'vendor/ember-data/ember-data.prod.js'
});
```

This was modified to comply with the new syntax:

```
app.import('vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js', { exports: { ember: ['default'] } });
```

however, I get the following error:

`app.import(vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js) - Passing modules object is deprecated. Please pass an option object with modules as export key (see http://git.io/H1GsPw for more info).`

I'm not sure how to proceed with this one so any help is much appreciated.

The new syntax is detailed [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/1121)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the deprecated message this is the new syntax.

```
app.import({
   development: 'vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js',
   production:  'vendor/ember-data/ember-data.prod.js'
}, {
   exports: {
       'ember-data': ['default']
      }
    });
```

Comment: I've changed my import to this syntax but the build-time error complaining about passing modules object is not going away!

Answer (score 0):

This error message was the result of leftovers from the old **ember-cli-ember-data** shim which was set to version *0.0.4* in the *package.json* file. I've changed it to *0.1.0* which is the latest as of this writing, removed (deleted) the old ember-cli-ember-data directory from the node_modules package directory and reran `npm install`. This resulted in the warning message disappearing.